# Problem with changing the variable inside of a Do Until loop

Tags: excel, vba

```
x = 0
Do Until x = Step
SrcVol = (Vol / DilPoints)
DilVol = Vol - SrcVol
Vol = 0.75 * Vol
Wb1.Sheets(1).Range("D4").Offset((2 * x) + k - 1, 0) = SrcVol
Wb1.Sheets(1).Range("D5").Offset((2 * x) + k - 1, 0) = DilVol
DilPoints = Range("D8").Offset(x, 0)
x = x + 1
Loop
```

Hello,
I am trying to offset this range in my VBA code and the DilPoints value gets lost after the offset. I have tried everything but the loop keeps dividing by zero after the first iteration of the loop. How do you make sure the value stays around and continues to collect data from other cells and not just default to zero. I have used the .Select and it makes the value go to -1.

Comment: Are you trying to keep count so each iteration you are adding to DilPoints?  If so then `DilPoints = DilPoints  + Range("D8").Offset(x, 0)` if not you need to explain it better.

Comment: What is `Step`? Is it a known numeric value? If yes, you can rewrite the loop as `For x = 0 to Step`. You can then remove the `x = 0` line and the `x = x + 1` line.